# pip install matplotlib: "no pkg-config"

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, virtualenv, pip

When I run `pip install matplotlib` (within a virtualenv), the first lines of output are:

```
Downloading/unpacking matplotlib
  Running setup.py egg_info for package matplotlib
    basedirlist is: ['/usr/local/', '/usr', '/usr/X11', '/opt/local']
    ============================================================================
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: 1.2.0
                    python: 2.7.3 (default, Dec 14 2012, 13:31:05)  [GCC 4.2.1
                            (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
                  platform: darwin

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                     numpy: 1.6.2
                 freetype2: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)

    OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
                    libpng: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)
                   Tkinter: Tkinter: 81008, Tk: 8.5, Tcl: 8.5
                      Gtk+: no
                            * Building for Gtk+ requires pygtk; you must be able
                            * to "import gtk" in your build/install environment
           Mac OS X native: yes
                        Qt: no
                       Qt4: no
                    PySide: no
                     Cairo: no
<snip>
```

**Note**

1. the "no pkg-config", and
2. the missing Qt library.

First, contrary to what the output above says, `pkg-config` *is* in fact installed and on the `PATH`:

```
% pkg-config --version
0.27.1
% which pkg-config
/usr/local/bin/pkg-config
```

Second, `qt` is available in the same directory where `freetype` and `libpng` were found:

```
% ls -l /usr/local/opt/{freetype,libpng,qt} | cut -c43-
/usr/local/opt/freetype -> ../Cellar/freetype/2.4.10/
/usr/local/opt/libpng -> ../Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/
/usr/local/opt/qt -> ../Cellar/qt/4.8.4/
```

My question has three parts:

> 1. Where does `pip install matplotlib` get that `basedirlist` (3rd line of the output above)?
> 2. What must I do differently so that `pip install matplotlib` will find `pkg-config`?
> 3. What must I do differently so that `pip install matplotlib` will find `qt`?

Answer (score 15):

**On Mac OS:** I use `which pkg-config` to check installation. If not, use brew to install and it works:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

Answer (score 8):

Just install freetype fonts to get matplotlib.

```
sudo apt-get install freetype*
```

All the matplotlib files are installed to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. Even if you want to install using pip installer, you need to fix freetype font problem, which can be done as stated above.

Comment: It didn't work for me. After I installed freetype*, I was still getting an error saying that freetype is required. I had to run `sudo apt-get install pkg-config`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't ask your specific questions, but my pip install matplotlib looked a lot like yours the other day. After five hours of slamming my head against the wall, this solution worked for me (from [practicalcomputing.org](http://practicalcomputing.org/node/69)

I got this set of commands to set up simlinks:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/include
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/include/freetype2/freetype /usr/local/include/freetype
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/include/ft2build.h /usr/local/include/ft2build.h
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/include/png.h /usr/local/include/png.h
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/include/pngconf.h /usr/local/include/pngconf.h
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/include/pnglibconf.h /usr/local/include/pnglibconf.h
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.dylib /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.dylib
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/lib/libpng.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib
```

It doesn't quite solve all your issues, but it solved my pkg-config issue (among others). Perhaps a similar link would help with QT.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but wanted to leave some possibly helpful crumbs.

I just dealt with a somewhat similar issue on Ubuntu 12.04 after trying to manually install an application that relied on a set of Python bindings that were manually installed within a virtualenv. The Python bindings were clearly installed in an appropriate place within my virtualenv, but the installer simply couldn't find them with `pkg-config`.

So to answer the original questions:

1. Where does pip install matplotlib get that basedirlist (3rd line of the output above)?

   - Not sure, but I'm guessing this might be something matplotlib's setup.py hardcoded after it detected your OS/distribution/version.
2. What must I do differently so that pip install matplotlib will find pkg-config?

   - I'm fairly certain it's finding `pkg-config` just fine; it's just not detecting any useful information for `freetype2` and `libpng`.
3. What must I do differently so that pip install matplotlib will find qt?

   - This is all based on experience on Ubuntu 12.04.
   - Installing `python-qt4` globally and creating a virtualenv with `--system-site-packages` enabled should make matplotlib happy, even if it means littering your global environment with modules. But I haven't been able to get pip to do anything useful when trying to install PyQt4 or python-qt in a virtualenv.
   - Installing `libqt4-dev` should also alleviate any dependency issues when building anything relying on Qt4.
   - If that didn't work, and others' answers here didn't help, this may shed some light on why pip is unhappy:

     - `man pkg-config`

> On  most  systems,  pkg-config  looks  in /usr/lib/pkgconfig, /usr/share/pkgconfig, /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig and /usr/local/share/pkgconfig for these files.  It will additionally look in the colon-separated (on Windows, semicolon-separated) list of directories specified by the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.
>
> `pkg-config` is looking for *.pc files; the fact that you found those dependencies installed somewhere doesn't mean `pkg-config` will find any *.pc files in those directories.
>
> As the man page indicates, if your packages are installed in funny places, you need to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` appropriately.
>
> If you've perchance installed your packages into your virtualenv, then you need to make sure your virtualenv's activate/deactivate commands update PKG_CONFIG_PATH appropriately. The only way I got this to work was to modify the `bin/activate` script in my virtualenv.
>
> - You can pretty much copy the existing code that maintains an `_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH` before updating `PATH` upon activation, and reverting back to `_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH` upon deactivation
> - Note that the existing code isn't perfect as of the time of this post, since if your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` was blank to begin with, you need a bit more logic to make sure it gets  cleared upon deactivation

Answer (score 0):

I had an almost identical error. I looked through the errors further down, and it seems like the problem was with freetype2.

I've had similarly frustrating issues with other packages that use freetype. For me, the compile error came from the following:

---

/usr/local/include/**freetype2**/freetype/*.h are the freetype files.

/usr/local/include is the search directory.

-Ifreetype/*.h is the flag passed to the compiler.

---

The problem is subtle, but I was able to get matplotlib to compile (which honestly, is approximately all I really care about) by copying /usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype -> /usr/local/include/freetype.

Hopefully this will help anyone who stumbles across this!